# Coloring the points by category in R

Tags: r, plot

I am creating a scatter plot in R using the following code:

```
plot(df_prob1$x1, df_prob1$x2, pch = df_prob1$y)
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

As seen in the above plot there are two categories, one represented by a square and the other by circle. I want these two categories to have different colors as well.

I did try using the following code:

```
plot(df_prob1$x1, df_prob1$x2, pch = df_prob1$y, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

And I get the following plot:

[image]

However, it is randomly coloring points and not taking the categories into consideration.

I also did trying passing the variable as value for col as such:

```
plot(df_prob1$x1, df_prob1$x2, pch = df_prob1$y, col = df_prob1$y)
```

But this didn't give a proper plot.

Comment: Try `col = c("red", "blue")[factor(df_prob1$y)]`. If it doesn't work, please post sample data.

Comment: @RuiBarradas It worked! If you can add this to answers, I can just accept it.

Comment: Done, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `df_prob1$y` as an index to the colors vector, `c("red", "blue")`. This can easily be done if the column `y` is coerced to a factor, since factors are coded internally as consecutive integers starting at 1. The following code uses the built-in data set `iris`, processed at the end of this answer.

```
clrs <- c("red", "blue")[factor(df_prob1$y)]
plot(df_prob1$x1, df_prob1$x2, pch = df_prob1$y, col = clrs)
```

[image]

**Test data.**

```
set.seed(1234)
df_prob1 <- subset(iris[c(1, 2, 5)], Species != "virginica")
df_prob1 <- df_prob1[sample(nrow(df_prob1), 50), ]
df_prob1[[3]] <- as.numeric(df_prob1[[3]] == "setosa")
names(df_prob1) <- c("x1", "x2", "y")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ggplot library for this :

```
library(ggplot) #install it if you dont have

ggplot(df_prob1,aes(x1,x2))+geom_point(aes(color = factor(y), shape = factor(y)))
```

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) [plot](/questions/tagged/plot)